# How to re-publish already published InfoPath list to different Sharepoint List?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath2010

I have created one InfoPath list and published it to my SharePoint test site. Now I want to publish the same InfoPath list to my final SharePoint site. When I open or 'save as' the InfoPath list, the previously published site location is always attached to it. But I want to change the publish location to different site. If I am not able to do that then I need to create similar InfoPath list and then publish it to different location. But it's all wastage of time.

I have read the same article posted here but I didn't get the solution. Please anyone could help me to fix my problem.

Answer (score 2):

First save the InfoPath to a different location using save as.

Then publish the form to the new destination by doing:

1. Go to the File Tab
2. Select Publish from the toolbar on the left
3. Select Sharepoint Server
4. Specify details of the destination: Server address, list name, etc

The form will then be available on the specified destination